# Word created from Workflow shows HTML tags too

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, word

I manage to create Word document in a Document Library based on values in some columns in a list.

My problem is that I try to format values with HTML tags in order to make values,bold or make some HTML tables, this values looks fine in list and columns in Content Type that been used of my Document Library but when I open the created documents then then shows all HTML tags instead of making for instance table or bold the content.

I have roughly done the following:

1. Create a list with some multi line (Rich Text Format)
2. Created a Document Library
3. Created Content Type with proper columns/site columns), one of the of type multi line with Rich Text Format.
4. Document Library configured to use this Content Type
5. Create Word template in order to use columns from Content Type
6. Workflow(2010) in the list which created Word.

But as I told I get all HTML tags in the created document. 
Any Idea what cause the issue?